# json array return as count in a key javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a json object that has json array inside

```
{
  "0": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020060",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020025",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020027",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020057",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
}
```

how can i convert the json array into count so that the response would look like this?

```
{
   "0" : "1",
   "1" : "3"
}
```

Comment: Get the keys, iterate/map to to find the key and its length.. it would be great if you can try this out and if you are still stuck, ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const jsonObj = {
  "0": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020060",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020025",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020027",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020057",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
};
const countObj = {};
for ( const key in jsonObj) {
  countObj[key] = jsonObj[key].length;
}
console.log(countObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to count the length of the array for each index, then here you go,

```js
const obj = {
  "0": [{
    "accountId": "2020060",
    "status": "0"
  }],
  "1": [{
      "accountId": "2020025",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020027",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020057",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
}

const result = {};


for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  result[key] = val.length
}

console.log("result", result)
```

On the other hand, if you want to make the count based on the `status` field, then here you go,

```js
const obj = {
  "0": [{
    "accountId": "2020060",
    "status": "0"
  }],
  "1": [{
      "accountId": "2020025",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020027",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020057",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
}

const result = {};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  let count = 0;
  val.forEach(({
    status
  }) => {
    if (key === status)
      count++;
  })
  result[key] = count
})

console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Object.keys and reduce.

```
const arr ={
  "0": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020060",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "accountId": "2020025",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020027",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2020057",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
}

const newArr = Object.keys(arr).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return { ...acc, [rec]: arr[rec].length }
}, [])

display.log(newArr)
```